# stackoverflow.com slowdown?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, performance

As of about 5 minutes ago, stackoverflow.com has slowed down to a near halt.. Meta Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault seems okish though.

What's up? O_o

Comment: Yep I see that too (from Ireland)

Comment: I loaded it just fine here in New England, and just opened a brand new question that was just asked.

Comment: No visible slowdown for me. (Atlanta)

Comment: I think there's a crab pinching the intertubes between your side and our side.  Trucks are flowing fine here.

Comment: @Will the clog is too big to be a crab. It's either a whole group (swarm? herd?), or an alligator

Comment: Located a video of the event!  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f17abJOMel4

Answer (score 4):

This is a queue issue with one of our web servers approximately 1/6 users are experiencing, we are working on the problem now.

*Update:* After some tweaks, the request queue is empty now, we'll continue to watch this today and make more adjustments if needed.

Comment: I dunno... I'm in favor of the crabs-pinching-tubes theory.

Comment: @Will, more like worms chewing on capillaries.

Comment: @Will - Well, it was a software crab :)